# JAVA - Create HashMap using string

Tags: java, hashmap

I am beginner in JAVA. I am want to store `session` and `max-age` value in `hashmap` and i am receiving this type of string in response. How i can achieve that.

```
session=e6cb242ea51874c73d0f323dfgdf5455e4c; path=/; max-age=43200; HttpOnly
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: there are many different ways of doing it, you can simply start by searching for `session=` and then look for the first occurrence of `;`, take the substring in between. Then repeat for `max-age=`. Alternatively, use regex. Alternatively, use one of available cookie parsers.

Comment: Hint, use split with `, ` note the space the for each element of the result split search for string that contain session or max-age the split with = and store the first value of each split as a key and the other as a value

Comment: @YCF_L you mean `;`?

Comment: @khachik I mean `Map<String, String> result = Arrays.asList(input.split(";\\s*")).stream()
        .filter(s -> s.contains("session") || s.contains("max-age"))
        .map(s -> s.split("="))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1]));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Java 8+ you can easilly use:

```
String input = "session=e6cb242ea51874c73d0f323dfgdf5455e4c; path=/; max-age=43200; HttpOnly";
Map<String, String> result = Arrays.asList(input.split(";\\s*")).stream()
        .filter(s -> s.contains("session") || s.contains("max-age"))
        .map(s -> s.split("="))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1]));
```

Outputs

```
session=e6cb242ea51874c73d0f323dfgdf5455e4c
max-age=43200
```

Edit

> ...I am getting headerfield is `List<String> List<String> cookies =
>   connection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");`

In this case you can use flatMap instead :

```
List<String> cookies = ...;//Some data
Map<String, String> result = cookies.stream()
        .flatMap(c -> Arrays.stream(c.split(";\\s*")))
        .filter(s -> s.contains("session") || s.contains("max-age"))
        .map(s -> s.split("="))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1]));
```

Comment: getting Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )  by spliting split(";\\s*")).

Comment: @Ankita what did you mean? are you using Java 8+ ? please take a look at this [demo](https://ideone.com/X6kcJd)

Comment: yes i am using Java 8+. I problem might be that i am getting headerfield is List<String>

`List<String> cookies = connection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
`

Comment: @Ankita In this case you can use flatMap instead check my edit

Answer (score 0):

Something basic like this can be used:

```
   {
            HashMap<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
            String data = "session=e6cb242ea51874c73d0f323dfgdf5455e4c; path=/; max-age=43200; HttpOnly";
            String[] dataArr = data.split("; ");
            String session = null;
            String maxAge = null;
            for (String part : dataArr) {
                if (part.startsWith("session")) {
                    session = part.split("=")[1];
                }
                if (part.startsWith("max-age")) {
                    maxAge = part.split("=")[1];
                }
            }

            if (session != null && maxAge != null) {
                resultMap.put(session, maxAge);
            }
        }
```